# How to schedule a task with the command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

I want to know how to schedule a task using the command prompt.
Now I know you can probably find this on the internet, but I haven't found what I've been looking for.

The problem is that the operating system I have to do it on is in Swedish (Windows Server 2003 in Swedish).

It needs to run a program located at: 'C:\Documents and Setting\Administratör\Skrivbord\Midnight.exe'.

It should run around midnight, every day.

Does anybody know how to schedule this in cmd?
I do have administrator rights, so privileges shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I feel your pain - once I had to uninstall IE on a laptop running windows in Korean

Comment: should really go to superuser.com

Comment: The worse thing is, I completely need to configurate it for running a server for a game in development, nightmare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use schtasks windows utility in a .bat file or manually in CMD :

```
schtasks /create /ru Admin /rp paswd /tn "daily work" /tr "C:\Documents and Setting\Administratör\Skrivbord\Midnight.exe" /sc daily /st 23:55:00
```

Swedish should'nt be a special case :)

off course `/ru` is the username which we'll be used to run the task

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do it, I just remembered about it today :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the AT command to put an entry in the scheduler service [TechNet on AT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755618%28WS.10%29.aspx)